# Ruby - gem instagram parser error on response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram, faraday

Faraday Parsing Error 757

I'm new with Ruby and i'm trying to do a simple instragram integration using [instagram gem](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem).

I already configured tokens (access_token, client_secret, client_id) with Insagram.config()

Now i'm facing an error while trying to get recent media from instagram inside my controller.

The request:

```
@medias = Instagram.user_recent_media(196583629, {:count => 1})
```

The error:

```
Faraday::Error::ParsingError at /contests/385
757: unexpected token at '�'
```

Console:

```
faraday_middleware (0.9.1) lib/faraday_middleware/response/parse_json.rb:11:in `block in <class:ParseJson>'
```

I don't know if might be the response that i'm getting is broken etc..
Is there a way  to check how and what's my response ?

Appreciate any help :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate this, but the userid you gave is protected.

However, the following code works ok for me (using Snoop Doggs ID: 1574083)

```
require 'instagram'

Instagram.configure do |config|
  config.client_id = ENV['INSTA_CLIENT']
  config.client_secret = ENV['INSTA_SECRET']
end

@medias = Instagram.user_recent_media(1574083, {:count => 1})

puts @medias.first
```

However, unexpected token errors basically imply that the JSON given by the server is not valid json, normally because it's not JSON at all or it's invalid (leading `"` for example...)

If you do a manual curl of that userid, what do you get?

`curl https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/196583629/media/recent/?client_id='clientidhere'`

Comment: This feels vaguely familiar feeling that this could also possibly be emojis?

Comment: Thanks for the response ! I was thinking about that... I need to do a few more tests. But do you have a clue about hanndling with emojis on response ? @Peter Souter

Comment: Well, on my machine emojis work fine in iTerm2, but it might be an encoding thing...